# Change .htaccess form a Path with PHP

Tags: php

i have a htaccess file:

```
AuthName "LogIn Interner Berei"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/www/web502/html/login/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

and a Session Login System:

```
if ( $Account->logged ) 
    { 

    } else {

    }
```

and how can i make that if logged in disable the htaccess file?

Comment: You don't. Basic auth via `.htaccess` is either on or off, there is no 'sometimes'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purely technically, you can edit an .htaccess file like any other using file editing functions like [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.fwrite.php).

**But please don't even think about that option!**

Your PHP-code is responsible to manage the logged-in state, not your .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Let me put it this way. If there is some kind of "While I'm doing development, disable mod rewrite automatically, so it doesn't get in the way", there are better waPHPys of acomplish this.

.htaccess runs before the script you are running is even parsed, mostly figuring out what would be done to a request. Apache caches the .htaccess files so it doesn't have to reread them every time, and looks for changetime newer then when it was cached. So the only way to do this would be: delete the file after login, and that would pretty much destroy things. So you see ... there is no way to do this, this way.

You can however modify .htaccess file to suit your needs.

Why more specifically do you want do this, i'm curious ?